# TFP401: 24-bit TFP401 to drive an 18-bit LCD panel, possible?

Tags: lcd, hdmi

We would like to use this LCD panel as it matches customer dimensions perfectly:
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sharp-microelectronics/LS037V7DW03A/425-2871-ND/4862435

This display has 6-bits per colour so 18-bits RGB.

TFP401 has 24-bits RGB or 8-bits per colour.

1) Can we still use TFP401 to drive the panel? this means some pins won't be connected.

2) video signal input is from HDMI

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the TI chip or Adafruit board?

The board has a "40 pins TTL RGB" while your Sharp panel has a 51 pins connector.

It is also necessary to configure the decoder with the correct panel resolution as there is no automatic detection here.

18bits vs. 24bits isn't a problem, just don't use LSB bits.

Comment: we plan to create our own driver PCB using TFP401 chip. which decoder can do the correct panel resolution?

Comment: @Ariel Narboada Sorry. It's not the decoder. Just a separate EEPROM with correct EDID data.

Comment: Hi Temlib, any sample EEPROM chip? again much appreciated mate!